# Как создать сериализатор сложной модели Django Rest

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь сериализовать сложную модель:

Model:

```
    class Order (models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        summ =models.CharField(max_length=15,default='0')
        delivery = models.ForeignKey('Delivery')
        success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        paymentMethod = models.ForeignKey('Payments')
        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.id)

    class OrderProduct(models.Model):
        order=models.ForeignKey('Order')
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        product = models.ForeignKey('product.Product')
        additionals = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
        count = models.IntegerField()
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.id


    class Delivery(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        delivery_time = models.DateTimeField()
        delivery_adress = models.TextField()
        phone = models.TextField()
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.phone

    class Payments(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        date_create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_change = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        title = models.TextField();
        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

Сериализаторы:

```
class DeliverySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Delivery
        fields = ('id', 'delivery_time','delivery_adress','phone')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Delivery.objects.create(**validated_data)   


class PaymentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Payments
        fields = ('id', 'title')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Payments.objects.create(**validated_data)   



class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    delivery = DeliverySerializer(read_only=True)
    paymentMethod = PaymentsSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'delivery', 'paymentMethod','summ','success') 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
        paymentsMethod_data = validated_data.pop('paymentMethod')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for delivery_data in deliverys_data:
            Delivery.objects.create(order=order, **delivery_data)
        for paymentMethod_data in paymentsMethod_data:
            Payments.objects.create(order=order, **paymentMethod_data)
        return order
```

View:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def order_post(request, format=None):

   #List all snippets, or create a new snippet.

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Мне необходимо чтобы данные, которые приходят одним пакетом корректно со всеми связями записывались в базу данных.

Каждый раз отправляя json получаю ошибку:

> ```
> deliverys_data = validated_data.pop('delivery')
> ```
>
> KeyError: 'delivery'

Пример JSON:

```
[{"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":1,"title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false}]
```

Comment: У вас в OrderSerializer поля delivery и paymentMethod обозначены как read_only="только для чтения", естественно их нет в validated_data.

Comment: @Chikiro без этого поля получаю
"non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]

Comment: Так вы передаете список из одного словаря, передавайте только словарь, не оборачивая его в список.

Comment: @Chikiro Передаю теперь {"delivery":{"delivery_time":"2016-05-31T12:18:47Z","delivery_adress":"123","phone":"123"},"paymentMethod":{"id":1,"title":"123124123"},"summ":"23","success":false} возвращает 500 с ошибкой      return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: order_order.delivery_id may not be NULL

Comment: Теперь надо смотреть логику сохранения моделей. Сначала надо сохранить delivery, потом подставить id в order.delivery_id и сохранить order.

Comment: @Chikiro поправил, теперь другая ошибка - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721134/how-to-serialize-relation тут подробнее

Comment: И вам там уже ответили :)

Comment: @Chikiro Да, заметил, спасибо)) Создайте пожалуйста ответ с правильным Json и советом убрать - помечу его как решение, а то самому создавать ответ после Ваших подсказок как-то наверное неправильно)